# Instance variables assigned in call to super class function are accessed as nil

Tags: inheritance, lua

#### Problem

I've encountered something odd when working with calls up an inheritance chain.

Suppose I have the following:

```lua
local Animal = classes.class()

local numAnimals = 0

function Animal:init (name)
    self.name = name
    numAnimals = numAnimals + 1
    self.id = numAnimals
end

local Cat = classes.class(Animal)

function Cat:init(name, breed)
    self.super:init(name)
    self.breed = breed
end
```

When creating instances, this is fine. But suppose inside `Animal:init` I want to make a reference to `self.id` after its assignment, to do something with it, when initially called from `Cat:init`:

```lua
local Animal = classes.class()

local numAnimals = 0

function Animal:init (name)
    self.name = name
    numAnimals = numAnimals + 1
    self.id = numAnimals
    print('My ID is '..self.id) -- this returns an error and self.id is nil
end

local Cat = classes.class(Animal)

function Cat:init(name, breed)
    self.super:init(name)
    self.breed = breed
end
```

For some reason, when `self.super:init(name)` is called, referencing instance attributes inside the super class `init` has them as `nil`. Any thoughts on what is happening? I believe the issue is described in the "Bugfix" section [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/YetAnotherClassImplementation), where overridden super class functions using instance variables have a bug. While there is a defined fix for that, not sure if it is actually applicable as the reference code for that article is no longer available.

#### Supporting Code

```lua
local classes = {}

classes.Object = {}
classes.Object.class = classes.Object

function classes.Object:init (...)
end

function classes.Object.alloc (mastertable)
    return setmetatable({}, {__index = classes.Object, __newindex = mastertable})
end

function classes.Object.new (...)
    return classes.Object.alloc({}):init(...)
end

function classes.Object:instanceOf (class)
    
    if self.class == class then
        return true
    end
    if self.super then
        return self.super:instanceOf(class)
    end
    return false
end

function classes.class (baseclass)
    
    local classdef = {}
    
    baseclass = baseclass or classes.Object
    
    setmetatable(classdef, {__index = baseclass})
    
    classdef.class = classdef
    
    function classdef.alloc (mastertable)
        
        local instance = {super = baseclass.alloc(mastertable)}
        
        setmetatable(instance, {__index = classdef, __newindex = mastertable})
        return instance
    end
    
    function classdef.new (...)
        
        local instance = {}
        
        instance.super = baseclass.alloc(instance)
        setmetatable(instance, {__index = classdef})
        
        instance:init(...)
        return instance
    end

    return classdef
end
```

Comment: What's probably happening is that the assignment to `self.id` writes to the class rather than the instance since you have `__newindex` set. I'd suggest greatly simplifying your class implementation; why are you working with `__newindex` at all?

Comment: @Luatic without `__newindex`, assignment of `self.id` and such belong to the inner table with key `["super"]` for the instance. I'd like to be able to access the variables `id` and `name` per instance via `self`. If I don't use `__newindex` then I must reference as `self.super.id`.

Answer (score 0):

1. The mistake is in the line `self.super:init(name)`
   `self.super` here is the (parent) class, but `init` must be applied to an instance being initialized, not to a class.
2. The OOP implementation you are using is weird.
   The `super` field is a pointer to some proxy which is unable to read what it was just written.  And a new proxy is allocated for every class instance being created.  I don't understand the reason behind that design decision.  Is it to be able to write short statement `self.super:method(...)` (which works only for "write-only" methods) instead of long one `self.super.method(self, ...)`?  Looks like an overkill.

Below is another, very simple implementation of Lua OOP:

```
--------  Simple Lua OOP

local BaseClass = {}
BaseClass.class = BaseClass

function BaseClass:init(...)
end

function BaseClass:new(...)
    local instance = setmetatable({}, {__index = self})
    instance:init(...)
    return instance
end

function BaseClass:instanceOf(class)
    if self.class == class then
        return true
    end
    if self.super then
        return self.super:instanceOf(class)
    end
    return false
end

function BaseClass:createSubClass()
    local SubClass = {}
    SubClass.class = SubClass
    SubClass.super = self
    return setmetatable(SubClass, {__index = self})
end

--------  Usage Example

local Animal = BaseClass:createSubClass()

local numAnimals = 0

function Animal:init(name)
    -- self = the instance to be initialized
    self.name = name
    numAnimals = numAnimals + 1
    self.id = numAnimals
    print('My ID is '..self.id)
end

local Cat = Animal:createSubClass()

function Cat:init(name, breed)
    -- self = the instance to be initialized
    -- self.super = the parent class of the class of the instance
    self.super.init(self, name)
    self.breed = breed
end

local cat = Cat:new("cat name", "cat breed")
```